# Как ждать ответ от пользователя в библиотеке Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'''
оставьте свои контакты и задайте свой вопрос.''')
    
#Здесь нужно как то осуществить ввод данных пользователя, 
#которые в последствии будут отправлены в другой чат в телеграмме

await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'''
Спасибо! Ваша заявка принята, ожидайте.''')
```

Comment: FSM не пробывали?

Comment: Не подскажите как его можно здесь реализовать?

Comment: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли. А не знаете, как сделать исключения? Что бы к примеру некоторые слова он не захватывал в память? У меня просто параллельно с вводом данных есть меню.

Comment: Напишите новый вопрос с кодом с вашей проблемой